# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when i try to archive the application

Tags: xcode, xcode6, armv7, mailcore

I am developing an iOS application in which i am using MailCore framework. When i am trying to install app from device from Xcode it works fine. Now when i am trying to create an archive to distribute the application i am getting error as below.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_EVP_DigestUpdate",
>   referenced from:
>         _otp_hash in libmailcore.a(otp.o)
>         _word2bin in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_EVP_DigestFinal", referenced from:
>         _otp_hash in libmailcore.a(otp.o)
>         _word2bin in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_EVP_get_digestbyname", referenced from:
>         _generate_otp in libmailcore.a(otp.o)
>         _otp_server_mech_step in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt", referenced from:
>         _enc_3des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o)
>         _dec_3des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o)   "_EVP_cleanup", referenced from:
>         _otp_common_mech_free in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_EVP_DigestInit", referenced from:
>         _otp_hash in libmailcore.a(otp.o)
>         _word2bin in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_OpenSSL_add_all_digests", referenced from:
>         _otp_server_plug_init in libmailcore.a(otp.o)
>         _otp_client_plug_init in libmailcore.a(otp.o)   "_DES_key_sched", referenced from:
>         _init_des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o)
>         _init_3des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o)   "_DES_cbc_encrypt", referenced from:
>         _enc_des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o)
>         _dec_des in libmailcore.a(digestmd5.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have already tried to set $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) as my Architectures for main as well sub projects. I have also set Build Active Architecture Only to NO.

Comment: Those symbols are within the `openssl` library.  How did you get it working during development?

Comment: I have set all architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and able to build and run the application the only issue occurs when i am trying to create an archive of my app.

Comment: Yes but where did you get the openssl library from?  It's not a standard library for iOS is it?  or is it?

Comment: Yes i got it from mailcore framework. https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore
There is iOSPort repository

Comment: OK, so it doesn't contain the `armv7` architecture.  You'll need to get one that does.  Or build it yourself.

Comment: I tried to create build for arm7 which also works fine when i am trying to build it the only issue is with creating the archive. for that i have set Build Active Architecture Only to NO.

Comment: Maybe you should use mailcore2. It won't use openssl.